# my activated rout doesn't find params in url. how should i fix it?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a web-app in angular and the router doesn't seem to work correctly. I want it to find the id and studentId when I enter the URL.

in app-routing.module.ts i have these routs

```
{path: "Classes", component: ClassListComponent, children : [
    {path: ":id",
    children:[
      {path: '', component: StudentListComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix',
      children : [
        //{path: '', component: TableComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: ':studentId/TimeTable', component: TableNavComponent, children: 
        [
          {path:'', component: TableComponent},
        ]},
      ]},
    ]},
  ]}
```

when I enter for example `http://localhost:4200/Classes/1/5/TimeTable`
I expect to be able to get `1` for `activatedRout.params['id']` (or any other way to get the params), but when I log it in my browser's console I receive `undefined`. although the studentId is fine.
for any other param that I add it just returns me the last one.

this is the last version of table code:

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.rout.paramMap.subscribe(
      param=> {
        if(param.has('studentId'))
        {
          this.studentId = param.get('studentId');
          console.log(this.studentId);
          this.data.StudentId = this.studentId;
        }
        if(param.has('id'))
        {
          this.ClassId = param.get('id');
          console.log(this.ClassId);
          this.data.ClassId = this.ClassId;
        }
        this.data.initTable(this.studentId);
    }
    )

    }
```

and in the console, I only receive 5 which is studentId and there is no sign of id.

Comment: I think you should review your route configuration. It should looks like: ` path: 'Classes/:classId', component: ClassListComponent,` and so on.

Comment: but after adding an other param to the routs it can find neither id nor studentId.

Comment: can you share component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get parameter some of them are

*1: Reading from the Snapshot*

```
const routeParams = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params;
console.log(routeParams.id);
```

*2: Via Subscriptions*

```
this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        console.log(routeParams.id);
});
```